# Java SMS API for Modem

Tags: java, sms, modem

I need a Java API that i can use to receive and send SMS messages. I already know of SMSLIB, but am wondering if there is a better one out there.

Answer (score 2):

What I found are the following links. They are simple sample code and only for sms receive and send from GSM modem via com port. Easy to modify and use them in own program. They are not like SMSLib(so many features but need a few third parties library and complex to use(at least for me)).

h t t p://blog.jservlet.com/post/2008/01/27/Object-SMS-send-and-receive-SMS-from-GSM-card-SIM-with-JAVA-Communication-API

h t t p://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22

h t t p://sourceforge.net/projects/java-sms-api/